# racing pigeon pedigree Design method by html with style

Tags: racing, pigeon, pedigree

I want a design racing pigeon pedigree by html with style
Where any pigeons  can be added and its data recorded, then it will be automatically added to
I will put an example to illustrate the method
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5rD.jpg)

I tried a lot, but I couldn't create the same idea